# Approve step in DAO refund - Error: exceeds block gas limit

Tags: go-ethereum, the-dao, thedao-refund

I'm following the steps from this URL: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds#How_Do_I_Withdraw_The_DAO_ETH_Refund_Using_Go_Ethereum.3F

"How Do I Withdraw The DAO ETH Refund Using Go Ethereum?"

Specifically this line right here is causing the error: `var approve = theDAO.approve(theDAOWithdrawalAddress, theDAO.balanceOf(account), {from: account});`

Is there a way to adjust the instructions in the above link to lower the block gas limit or..?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your own gas limit by including the `gas` option in the transaction object passed in.

```
theDAO.approve(theDAOWithdrawalAddress, theDAO.balanceOf(account), {from: account, gas:<GAS_LIMIT_VALUE>});
```

See the [web3js documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) for all of the available options.

When not specified, it'll use a default value determined by recent activity on the blockchain (which is usually around 8 million. You can get the current default gas limit [here](https://ethstats.net/))